# outsource XXX.db.bson_serializer.ObjectID.createFromHexString(id) to a function?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express

I went through [this](http://blog.ijasoneverett.com/2013/04/a-sample-app-with-node-js-express-and-mongodb-part-2/) express tutorial. I was wondering if it is possible to outsource the following call to a separate function, as it is very very long?

```
employee_collection.db.bson_serializer.ObjectID.createFromHexString(id)
```

This is the whole file where the statement is called:

```
var Db = require('mongodb').Db;
var Connection = require('mongodb').Connection;
var Server = require('mongodb').Server;
var BSON = require('mongodb').BSON;
var ObjectID = require('mongodb').ObjectID;

EmployeeProvider = function(host, port) {
    this.db = new Db(
        'node-mongo-employee',
        new Server(host, port, {}),
        {safe: true}
    );
    this.db.open(function(){});
};

...

// find an employee by id
EmployeeProvider.prototype.findById = function(id, callback) {
    this.getCollection(
        function(error, employee_collection) {
            if( error )
                callback(error)
            else {
                employee_collection.findOne(
                    {_id: employee_collection.db.bson_serializer.ObjectID.createFromHexString(id)},
                    function(error, result) {
                        if( error )
                            callback(error)
                        else 
                            callback(null, result)
                    }
                );
            }
        }
    );
};

...

exports.EmployeeProvider = EmployeeProvider;
```

It's the controller of an express application. It's shortened, but should give you an idea of what it does. You can find the whole application on [Github](https://github.com/ijason/NodeJS-Sample-App).

I tried

```
getid = function( employee_collection, id ) {
    return employee_collection.db.bson_serializer.ObjectID.createFromHexString(id);
};
```

and called the function with

```
{_id: getid(employee_collection, id),
```

but I'm getting a very long ENOENT error with that one.

Comment: ? You already require `ObjectID` as a scoped variable. What is wrong with `new ObjectID(id)` where `id` is a hex string?

Comment: That's code from a tutorial. I'm not the author of it. I'm a beginner with NodeJs. It would be nice if you could elaborate your answer, as I don't have a clue what you mean ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Presuming that you are working with the basic node.js mongodb driver here and that you have `id` essentially coming in as something like a request parameter, which means it's just a string and looks something like:

```
"53cfba87e248860d16e1f7e1"
```

Then the import you have used here:

```
var ObjectID = require('mongodb').ObjectID;
```

Gives you a direct function to use. Just do this:

```
employee_collection.findOne({ "_id": ObejctID(id) },function(err,result) {

   // work in here
});
```

The `ObjectID` you are importing already implements this function.

Comment: Wow that's cool. It doesn't answer my original question, but I'll give you a big +1 for this.

Comment: @mles How does it not answer your question? Don't do what you are doing and do this. No problem. If I had to answer "why do I not fall off the end of a flat earth" with something that related to a flat earth rather than an alternative, then the world would never get anywhere. "Answers" are things that actually work.

Comment: I know that your answer works, I tested it! I can see that this is a way more elegant solution than outsourcing the code. However I'm coming from a novice perspective and my question was how to outsource a long call from deep within a function, rather than a sleek solution. I really appreciate your solution! Anyway, the outsourcing version as posted in the question works as well. I just didn't execute `npm start` from the base directory of the application. That was the real error.

Comment: @mles Geeez. But because I'm being nice `var short = my.really.super.long.ridiculous.functionname.with.sugar;` Welcome to JavaScript. Just objects.